# Append different div to divs loaded by ajax request(Infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using this [plugin](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/examples/default/) on my website. You will be able to see the HTML structure it is generating.  I am trying to insert custom div after every 5 divs. Since it is loaded asynchronously, I am not able to append div that I wanted. I tried adding the following code which is used in normal situation

```
$(".alm-reveal:eq(0)").append("<div>Firstdiv</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(1)").append("<div>Second Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(2)").append("<div>Third IMage</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(3)").append("<div>Fifth Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(4)").append("<div>Sixth Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(5)").append("<div>Seventh Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(6)").append("<div>Eigth Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(7)").append("<div>ninth Image</div>");
```

which obviously did not work. I also tried adding it in the success function.

```
success: function (data) {
    alm.AjaxLoadMore.success(data);
    $(".alm-reveal").append("<div>Firstdiv</div>");
}
```

But since it is in the loop, it is repeating. I am quite not sure how to achieve this. How do I trigger append function every time an ajax request is made and append different divs I wanted in proper place. Hope I am clear.

Comment: No, you are not clear. Please add `html` or create `jsfiddle`

Comment: This is the plugin for wordpress. Please visit this link ; https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/examples/default/ . I want to append different divs after every nth div with the class 'alm-reveal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question though I am not sure if this is the efficient way to do. But it works 100% the way I wanted.

```
if(data.indexOf("aj-l-main-entry-8") > -1) //Making sure AJAX div is loaded
      {
         if(document.getElementById("element-id") == null) { //Appending div only once 
         $("#id_of_the_div_you_want_to_append_to").append('<div></div>');
         }
      }
```

I have added the above code in the `success` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
    alm.AjaxLoadMore.success(data);
    $(".alm-reveal:last").append("<div>"+data+"</div>"); //selects last div in that class
}
```

every time you append, you should append to last div in that particular class

Comment: Yeah. I tried that. But I want to append different divs. :/

Comment: @Venky Different Div in the sense can u explain me

Comment: @Venky can tell the dom structure u need

Comment: Different div as in, appended div should have different content.

Comment: @Venky <div>Firstdiv</div>
<div>Seconddiv</div>
<div>Thirddiv</div>

Comment: If you can please visit this page and enter the following in the console $(".alm-reveal:eq(0)").append("<div>Firstdiv</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(1)").append("<div>Second Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(2)").append("<div>Third IMage</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(3)").append("<div>Fifth Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(4)").append("<div>Sixth Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(5)").append("<div>Seventh Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(6)").append("<div>Eigth Image</div>");
$(".alm-reveal:eq(7)").append("<div>ninth Image</div>");
...  then what you see is the structure I need. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Venky in data you will in this order means Firstdiv
Second Imagec
Third IMage
Fifth Image

Comment: @Venky you will have data in array are in string format

Comment: if you have not mistaken, the div that I want to append will have completely different data from the data that I am getting from the AJAX request. What I am getting from AJAX request is the list for articles. So, after every nth article, I want to place a custom image( lets assume). Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80363/discussion-between-selva-and-venky).

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
        alm.AjaxLoadMore.success(data);
        $(".alm-reveal:last").append("<div>"+data+"</div>"); //selects last div in that class
    }
```

**data** should be passed accordingly to get different data in the div.